# How to exclude images when exploding a string by a dot

Tags: php

I have this string for example:

```
 $str = 'The quick fox. <img src="image.jpg" /> Jumped over. The lazy Dog.';
```

I need to get the first two sentence (or first two dots). How can I skip `<img src="image.jpg" />` from being exploded when using
`$arr   = explode('.',  $str);`

Here's my current code.

```
$len   = 2;
$arr    = explode('.',  $str);
$arr2   = array_slice($arr, 0, $len);

$str = implode('.', $arr2).'.';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use strip_tags function to remove all html tags from the string.

like this

```
$arr = explode('.', strip_tags($str));
```

for more information http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

**--Edit--**

```
$arr = explode('.', strip_tags($str));
```

will not modify ur original string.it remains as it is.

```
$str = 'The quick fox. <img src="image.jpg" /> Jumped over. The lazy Dog.';
$arr = explode('.', strip_tags($str));
print_r($arr);
//output :- Array ( [0] => The quick fox [1] => Jumped over [2] => The lazy Dog [3] => ) 
echo "<br/>".$str;
//output :- The quick fox. <img src="image.jpg" /> Jumped over. The lazy Dog.
```

Comment: I need the image tag to remain in the string but it should not be exploded.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't too clear, I need to implode it back. Kindly see my updated question.